# How do i differentiate different subclasses in a array of the superclass?

Tags: java, arrays, subclass, superclass, instanceof

My setup is the following. 
I have a superclass called "bottles" and 2 different subclasses, "water" and "soda". There's an array filled with countless of both of these and my goal is to write a method that returns the total liter values of only one of these subclasses. What would be the best way to accomplish that? As far as i understand 'instanceof' has no use here.

To clarify i only want to know what operator/method is used to compare:

```
if (bottles[0]==soda){
      ...
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using? How are these classes implemented?
Too few details.

Comment: why you think "instanceof has no use" you can use it as bottles[0] instanceof water

Comment: Soda instanceof water didn't compile so i assumed it makes no difference if the array is of type bottle.

Comment: Please share your attempts and possible error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, instanceof still works.

However, how about you put the logic of your counting-liter-criteria in your subclass method? So that, if you want to count the liter of sweet drink in your bottles, your water should return 0 but your soda should return real liter. Since the subclasses know the best of itself, it is better you let them give you the answer directly. Don’t break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bottles[i] instanceof Soda) {
    return bottles[i].getRealLiter();
    }
 else if(bottles[i] instanceof Water) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you have control over Bottle classes and you still need to use `instanceof` in your code, you have problems with your design.

```
interface Bottle{
  void addLiters(LiterCalculator calculator);
}
```

LiterCalculator will look something like this,

```
interface LiterCalculator{
   public addWater(int liters);
   public addSoda(int liters);
   //so on
}
```

And SodaBottle is responsible of adding itself;

```
class SodaBottle implements Bottle {
private int liters;

public void addLiters(LiterCalculator calculator) { calculator.addSoda(liters); }
}
```

So your flow is no longer responsible of different calculations of Bottle instances.